# CSS: select next element, that wrapped in a span

Tags: css

I have such a problem. My markup:

```
<span>
    <i class="rectangle"></i>
</span>
<span>
    <i class="circle"></i>
</span>
```

And I need to choose `span .circle` that goes after `span .rectangle`.
And I don't know how. Selector `span>.rectangle+span>.circle` doesn't work.
https://jsfiddle.net/kipris/refb2a6g/

Comment: There is a proposed `:has()` selector but not supported by any browser yet.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman, is it still there?

Comment: As I know, there is no way to select `parent` in `css3`. you should use `javascript` or `jQuery`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Yes, in Initial Draft Phase. Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't. In css you can go either into or to next, but not upper ot to previous.

Try searching for other ways. If you tell original problem, it's possible that some solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/refb2a6g/1/

```
<span>
    <i class="rectangle"></i>
</span>
<span>
    <i class="circle"></i>
</span>

i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

span + span i {
  background-color: green;
}
```

(if I understood correctly)

Comment: Nope, he asks for `span:has(.rectangle) + span .circle` - the circle which follows rectangle if look on their parent spans.

Comment: ok, got it, he wants to go one level above in specificity.

Yeah, agree, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Css can't select a parent element like it's explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)
I would recommend to put containers like this

```
<span class="rectangle-container">
    <i class="rectangle"></i>
</span>
<span class="circle-container">
   <i class="circle"></i>
</span>
```

css:

```
i {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: red;
}
.circle {
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.rectangle-container + .circle-container .circle {
  background-color: green;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epbjy7y9/)